# How to read a PPT file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, powerpoint

I have PPT file on desktop named as "slide.ppt". I want to read all slides of this PPT file in my `ReadSlide` function as below

```
public void ReadSlide(){


}
```

How can I read all slide from a PPT file in my C# code?

Comment: Take a look at this. https://github.com/asposeslides/Aspose_Slides_NET

Comment: It might help if you define what you mean by "read a slide".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use as below

```
public void ReadSlide(){

            string filePath= @"C:\Users\UserName\Slide.pptx";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(filePath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

            string presentation_textforParent = "";
            foreach (var item in presentation.Slides[1].Shapes)
            {
                var shape = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape)item;
                if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    if (shape.TextFrame.HasText == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                    {
                        var textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
                        var text = textRange.Text;

                        presentation_textforParent += text + " ";
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: You should never use Automation in a server process. [Microsoft strongly discourages it and it not supported.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 3):

If it was an PPTX, you could read it using OpenXML. Since you specifically asked for PPT, it is a little harder.

You shouldn't use Automation / Interop for sure, since [it isn't supported in a server environment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

That means you have to use third-party tools to read the PPT. If you google for them, you will see a long list of them. I have never worked with it, but [Aspose](https://github.com/asposeslides/Aspose_Slides_NET) seems to do the job very well.