# How to detect if the powerpoint has external link with C#

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint

I am working on windows application (winform) which converts PPT to video with slide timing information.
However when there is an external link(like images with external link) in the PPT file then PPT application shows the security alert blocking the slide show.
I am not going to change the security level as it is used on the server.

I would like to detect if the ppt/pptx file has any external links before starting the slide show and inform the user to remove the external links.

```
  foreach (Slide slide in pptPresentation.Slides)
  {
    // detect if any slide has external link
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to read a PPT file in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29093417/1260204)

Comment: @Igor It detects if ppt has text field

Comment: You can use that same code and a starting point, figuring out if there is a link should be easy.

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out, Can you please provide any sample code to detect as a Image and its location

Comment: @SachinSonone Each slide has a hyperlinks collection that you can iterate through. Each hyperlink has an .Address property you can examine to determine whether it fits your criteria for "external" or not.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg. but here is what worked for me
`
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape obj in slide.Shapes)
                {

                    if (obj.Type == MsoShapeType.msoLinkedOLEObject ||
                        obj.Type == MsoShapeType.msoLinkedPicture)
                    {
                        // external link
                        InvalidSlides.Add(slide.SlideIndex);
                    }
                  
                }`

Comment: @SachinSonone Glad you caught that also. External links can be hyperlinks, OLE Links or linked pictures, videos or sounds.  If you want to catch everything, you'll need to look for all of those.